# how to check full error log in Zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I am newbie in ZF and this is my first test. i am getting

```
An error occurred
An error occurred
```

my error.phtml is

```
<h1>An error occurred</h1>
  <h2><?php echo $this->message ?></h2>
  <?php if (isset($this->exception)): ?>

  <h3>Exception information:</h3>
  <p>
      <b>Message:</b> <?php echo $this->exception->getMessage() ?>
  </p>

  <h3>Stack trace:</h3>
  <pre><?php echo $this->exception->getTraceAsString() ?>
  </pre>

  <h3>Request Parameters:</h3>
  <pre><?php echo $this->escape(var_export($this->request->getParams(), true)) ?>
  </pre>

  <?php endif ?>
```

and this is what i have in my IndexAction

```
$this->view->title="My Places";
$this->view->headTitle($this->view->title);
$Places=new Places();
echo "<pre>";var_dump($Places->fetchAll(null,'date_created DESC', 4)); echo "</pre>";
```

and my module file id

```
class Places extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    protected $_name='places';
    public function fetchLatest($count=10)
    {
        return $this->fetchAll(null,'date_created DESC', $count);
    }

}
```

**** EDIT **** 
ErrorController is

```
<?php

class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function errorAction()
    {
        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        if (!$errors || !$errors instanceof ArrayObject) {
            $this->view->message = 'You have reached the error page';
            return;
        }

        switch ($errors->type) {
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
                // 404 error -- controller or action not found
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
                $priority = Zend_Log::NOTICE;
                $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
                break;
            default:
                // application error
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
                $priority = Zend_Log::CRIT;
                $this->view->message = 'Application error';
                break;
        }

        // Log exception, if logger available
        if ($log = $this->getLog()) {
            $log->log($this->view->message, $priority, $errors->exception);
            $log->log('Request Parameters', $priority, $errors->request->getParams());
        }

        // conditionally display exceptions
        if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {
            $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
        }

        $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
    }

    public function getLog()
    {
        $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        if (!$bootstrap->hasResource('Log')) {
            return false;
        }
        $log = $bootstrap->getResource('Log');

        return $log;
    }


}
```

How can i know what caused this error? (how can i see full error log?)
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `/application/configs/application.ini`

set

```
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

For the environment you are in. If you don't know which one you are in, put it temporarily under `[production]`.

Comment: I have tried this already and tried 
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
but all of this didn't show anything !!

Comment: Have you modified your ErrorController then? Because your error view script doesn't seem to be getting the exceptions.

Comment: i have edited the question above (erroController has been added to the question)

Comment: Try and comment out the conditional `if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {` so that `$this->view->exception = $errors->exception;` always gets assigned and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Yes,, now i got the error, but as long as there is an error, why didn't it show it normally!!
however thanks again for your help

Comment: @Lina the ErrorController isn't getting `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions` as `true` for some reason, make sure you aren't putting it `false` somewhere in your application or config.